# Layout Views in LinearLayout Programmatically

Tags: android

I am trying to position a TextView and an ImageView within a LinearLayout programmatically. The problem is that the textview is always on top of the imageview, and I would like to it be underneath. I cannot find a way to imitate the `android:layout_below=` xml attribute in the java UI approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply switch the order of your two views.

For example:

```
linear.addView(image);
linear.addView(text);
```

instead of:

```
linear.addView(text);
linear.addView(image);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(context);
lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
TextView textView = new TextView(context);

lin.addView(imageView);
lin.addView(textView);
```

the first component `ImageView` should be placed in the `LinearLayout` first, before the `TextView`.

Edit: oops forgot about "programmatically"